# Mule ESB: Multiple instances of custom transformer are created during server start up

Tags: mule, mule-component

I created a new custom transformer: 
`MyCustomTransformer`, that extends `AbstractMessageTransformer`.

Than I defined: 
`<custom-transformer name ="myCustomTransformer"class="com.acme.MyCustomTransformer"/>` in Mule xml file.

And on the last step I started to use it via:

```
<transformer ref="myCustomTransformer">
```

All works as expected, with only one note: I see that 5 instances of `MyCustomTransformer` created during server startup.

And I have not an idea how to explain it. Why 5 instances? I defined only one.

Comment: How did you knew 5 instances got created? Any logs you can share?

Comment: Can you paste your whole configuration?